Manga where the protagonist can remove people from existence & memories; trip to space bestows blue-blooded kids with superpowers; time-traveling gods
I remember reading this manga back in 2014 from my city's local library. I read it in Vietnamese, but the art style is from Japan. It's about a made adult finding out about his superpower to control space, which he uses to remove people from existence along with others' memories of the target. Infrequently, people regain the memory of this removal and go crazy. This happened to his mother when he removed his dad as a kid. In the first arc of the story, his mother kills herself.
Later, he found out his power manifested after a trip to space when he was a kid. He was sent to space along with 12 (or 11) kids, who all developed special powers after returning from space. A notable point is that their blood turns blue when they use their power.
Here is a list of superpowers the kids received besides the protagonist,

 a girl who can read minds, but is blind when she returns from the trip. She read others' minds to move around.
a girl who can inject emotions into her voice. She becomes a popular singer.
a boy who can control time
a boy who can control the earth's axis (causing earthquakes) but ages rapidly when he uses his power
a girl who is immortal
a boy who can control people, but changes his gender as he uses his power. There is a bomb implanted in his brain in case he has some crazy thoughts.

More on the background, there is a company that creates BABEL, a translating system that allows people to understand any language. To use this system, people can opt to use headphones or to undergo surgery that permanently allows them to use BABEL.
Later, it is revealed that BABEL is a system that allows people free will from gods, and the gods are artificial beings sent back by future humans to speed up human evolution. However, the gods rebel and want to make humans their subordinates instead. Thus, the future humans traveled back in time and gave their remaining power to Jesus to liberate people.
That is what I remember. I would appreciate it if anybody could give me a name.

What language did you read that in?

I read it in Vietnamese, but that art  style is from Japan.

Can you clarify what you meant by "made adult"? Did you mean "male adult"?

This is Baptist: Manipulated Age of the Gods.
It's a six-volume, black & white Korean manhwa from 2008. Unfortunately, it's never been published in English, so there isn't much information about the plot on English-language websites. I've therefore lifted most of the text quoted below from a French-language website called Nautiljon and auto-translated it to English.

At the end of 2010, 13 children were sent into space to celebrate the New Year. But, while they are in space, the children find themselves left to their own devices, without being able to communicate with the outside world, for 13 hours. At the end of this time, the children are rescued, but what happened during those 13 hours?
Eight years later, Bono U. Meyer, one of the children of the expedition, is a young student like so many others, except that he is gifted and has an IQ of 240. But his world is not idyllic. His sister was interned, his mother on sedatives, and his father had disappeared. In addition, people he knew well in the past accuse him of having made people who never existed disappear. Crazy delusions, or mysterious truth?


According to a character profile for the protagonist, Bono U. Meyer, he was one of 13 children sent on a space expedition in the year 2010. Eight years later, his father has disappeared, his mother is on sedatives and commits suicide, he's accused of driving all his acquaintances crazy, and discovers that he has the power to erase people.

Bono is one of thirteen children who took part in the 2010 space expedition. Eight years later, Bono became very famous thanks to his IQ of 240, which allowed him to enter two faculties: medicine and law. Despite his facilities, Bono does not lead a quiet life: his mother is on sedatives, his father has "disappeared", and his sister Anna is in a psychiatric hospital.
After his mother's suicide, Inspector Lione, who suspects him of driving all his acquaintances crazy, begins to harass him.
After a tough interview with Lioner, Bono allies with one of Lioner's victims, Max Lumor. However, he turns out to be a psychopath who wants to kill Lioner and accuse Bono! But just as Max shoots Lioner, Bono "erases" Max.
Bono is forced to admit the truth: he really does have the power to erase people...
Bono tries to reconnect with captain Jack Cunningham, who seems to know a lot about the situation.

A character profile for Alison Green notes that she was also one of the children sent on the space expedition in 2010 and returned with paranormal powers like the others. Her power is the ability to control people's thoughts and she used it to become a popular singer.

Alison Green, like Bono, was part of the Space Expedition. She was quite close to Bono and Kumar.
As a child, she was easily scared and stressed, and felt reassured in the company of the two boys.
Like all the others, she returns from the expedition with paranormal powers. His allows him to control people's thoughts.
Because of this, she gained an ascendancy over the human race and became very haughty and self-confident.
It is thanks to her power that she became the very popular singer Magna.
When she reunites with Bono after years of separation, she tries to seduce him, declaring that she has always loved him. But what she wants more than anything is for Bono to make her "disappear" because she considers herself a monster.
Alison is a child spoiled by a very rich father, but neglected.

And a character profile for Eishwarya Kahn notes that she works for the Modos company that developed the Babel Universal Translator.

Eishwarya Kahn, or Eish, is part of the Modos company, which developed the Babel Universal Translator. Eish is in charge of human resources, but she knows nothing about the company where she works.

Finally, this review of Vol. 4 from a different French-language website, Manga Sanctuary, mentions a peer of Bono's named Satoshi, who is able to master time, and alludes to revelations about the birth of Jesus.

While Bono is looking for Kumar, he falls into the trap of Satoshi, who is able to master time. He then tries to fight the latter with his powers, which he had never done consciously before...
Faced with one of his "peers" who is used to using his power, Bono quickly realizes his limitations. But he owes his salvation to Alison... Having tracked down Kumar in India, our but's plans to travel to New Delhi when Bono is contacted by Lioner. The latter, who had given Father Enoch's diary to Young-Chan, also a former cosmonaut, invites Bono to join him in Korea. Their meeting will give rise to great revelations...
This fourth volume of Baptist is rich in information. While the story takes place in several places at the same time (India, Korea, Paris), the events taking place in Paris (with Terry, Gabriel and the famous comic book Nativity) find their resonance in those taking place in Korea, where the revelations are shattering. The fate of Lioner, the revelations about the birth of Jesus, the mention of Peter, Matthew, the "Three Kings", Gabriel... All this offers us a story that revisits the Bible in its own way, with a welcome touch of science fiction. We are carried away, intrigued, and all this can only make you want to learn a little more. On the graphics side, this time we are entitled to many very beautiful illustrations and the beginnings of the first volumes are less present here. But the particular side of the story and the graphics can also cause a feeling of rejection in the reader...
Full of revelations, this 4th volume of Baptist is devoured from start to finish. A mix of science fiction, fantasy, religion (totally revisited), the story captivates and the war that is coming between gods and humans promises to be thrilling... An excellent volume.


Yeah. That’s it. Tks

Are you referring to Platinum End, but it was originally released in 2015.
Found similar plot here

Mirai Kakehashi is a young orphaned high school student who lives with his abusive aunt and uncle after the death of his parents. One day, Mirai decides he cannot take it anymore and attempts to commit suicide, but is saved by a Guardian Angel called Nasse, who also gives Mirai special powers. Upon learning from Nasse that his aunt and uncle were responsible for the deaths of his father and mother due to their jealousy and hatred toward to them, Mirai uses the powers that she bestowed to him in order to enact justice upon them. This is only the beginning of Mirai’s story, however, as Nasse soon after informs him that God will retire in 999 days and thirteen candidates to replace him were selected, one of which is Mirai. To make matters worse, not only is Mirai forced to take part in the contest to decide the next God, but some of the other candidates will do anything to win, including killing all of the other candidates as soon as possible. To combat these ruthless killers, Mirai forms an alliance with several candidates who share his goal: to win the contest without killing any other competitors.


Hi. You could significantly improve this answer by editing it to more clearly explain how the plot of Platinum End matches that of the manga described in the question.

And a significant explanation as well, because this does not seem to match any of the plot recollections...

That’s not it. It was a pretty old manga.
